# a continuity question concerning metrics on probablility measures

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

For a metric space $M$, I'll write $Prob(M)$ for the Borel probability measures on $M$.
I am interested in metrics on $Prob(M)$, such as the Kantorovich distance (or other metrics).

If $f: M \rightarrow M'$ is continuous, is the induced map $Prob\ f : Prob(M) \rightarrow Prob(M')$ also continuous?  Is it true when "continuous" is replaced by "uniformly continuous"?

Is this known for the Kantorovich metric?  Or for any other metric?

I'm also interested case of discrete metrics. (This is the main application that I have in mind.)

Comment: It works for the topology of weak convergence of measures, using the change of variable theorem for image measures: If $g\in C_b(M)$, then $\int g~\mathrm d\mu\circ f^{-1}=\int g\circ f~\mathrm d\mu$.

Comment: I wrote two papers on this topic in 1995, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1727 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.6161

Answer (score 1):

There is the Fisher-Rao metric.   [Here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/Fisher-Rao-metric.pdf) is a paper on its uniqueness.
It plays a big role in information geometry. There are discrete versions of it also, see the references.